A figure I placed using subfloat has a mismatching number in the text when compared to the caption of the figure
I have a document with a figure comprising two images. I placed the image using subfloat. The hyperlink to the image gives me a spurious figure number. So, the figure is labelled Figure 5 by the caption, but Figure 2.3.3 in the test of the hyperlink.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}



\ref{fig:image}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\centering 
% 

\subfloat(a){%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
  
}
% 
\subfloat(b){%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}%

}
% 
\label{fig:image}
\caption[generic caption]{generic caption}
% % 
\end{figure}
\end{document}

How do I rectify this little niggle.
Thanks
Alex

you have the \label before the caption so are labelling the current section number not the figure
